# Creating a differential matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to create matrices `Dx` and `Dy` that give the partial diferentials in the x and y directions respectivly when multipled by column stack representation of 2D area (`x`) so that `Dx*x` will give me the partial derivetives in the x direction in vector form as well (the same dimentions as `x`).

The derivitives are aproximated by:

> f'(x,y) = 0.5*(f(x+1,y)-f(x-1,y)) for all x > 1 and x < n (the number of rows)
>
> f'(1,y) = f(2,y)-f(1,y)
>
> f'(n,y) = f(n,y)-f(n-1,y)

for Dx and similarly for Dy.

I tried creating the matrices using the fallowing code:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:n,1:m); % m,n - the dimentions of x
X = X(:)';
Y = Y(:)';
Dx = sparse(m*n,m*n);
Dy = sparse(m*n,m*n);

for x = 1:n
    for y = 1:m
        idx = y + (x-1)*m;
        if (x == 1)
            Dx(idx,:) = ((X == x+1) .* (Y == y)) - ((X == x) .* (Y == y));
        elseif (x == n)
            Dx(idx,:) = ((X == x) .* (Y == y)) - ((X == x-1) .* (Y == y));
        else
            Dx(idx,:) = 0.5*(((X == x+1) .* (Y == y)) - ((X == x-1) .* (Y == y)));
        end
        if (y == 1)
            Dy(idx,:) = ((X == x) .* (Y == y+1)) - ((X == x) .* (Y == y));
        elseif (y == m)
            Dy(idx,:) = ((X == x) .* (Y == y)) - ((X == x) .* (Y == y-1));
        else
            Dy(idx,:) = 0.5*(((X == x) .* (Y == y+1)) - ((X == x) .* (Y == y-1)));
        end
    end
end
```

But this takes too much time, I feel that there should be a faster to create `Dy` and `Dx`?

---

About `x`: for a 2D function represented by `X` so that `size(X)` is `[n m]`, then `x=X(:)` and `size(x)` is `[n*m 1]`

Answer (score 0):

Follow those steps:

1. Represent the operation using a Filter. Derivative Filters are easy the way you defined the above.
2. Create the Convolution Matrix using MATLAB's [`convmtx2()` Function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/convmtx2.html).

This will get you what you wanted.

#### Derivative Filters in Image Processing

Horizontal Derivative:
 * Forward Finite Difference - $ [-1, 1] $.
 * Backward Finite Difference - $ [1, -1] $.

Vertical Derivative:
 * Forward Finite Difference - $ [-1; 1] $.
 * Backward Finite Difference - $ [1; -1] $.

Comment: What filter would give me this?

Comment: This is not what I've asked for, what you are doing is calculating the derivatives for a specific vector (or image), what I want is to get a general  matrix that will give the derivatives of any vector of the right dimensions.

Comment: What I gave you create a Matrix A such that A * x is the the Derivative Vector where x is the Column Stack of the image.